# MySQL Trigger code never called

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a MySQL table like this

```
 ID    USER_ID   FIELD_ID    VALUE
 1        1         1          0
 2        1         2          2
 3        1         3          0<----- USER ID 0 
 .        .         .          .
 .        .         .          .
 .        .         .          .
 40       20        1          6
 41       20        2          3
 42       20        3          1<------ USER ID 1 
 .        .        .          .
 .        .         .          .
 .        .         .          .
 73       34        1          9
 74       34        2          6
 75       34        3          20<----- user ID 20
 .        .         .          .
 .        .         .          .
 .        .         .          .
```

field_id #3 above contains either "0" or the ID of another user.

I'm trying to write a MYSQL trigger that runs BEFORE UPDATE so that if user "A" is writing the ID of user B into field_id #3, and if user "B" field_id #3 is not "0" then write "0" in to user "A" field_id #3.

so the pseudo code for the trigger is basically:

```
  if (B["field_id3"]!="0") THEN
      A["field_id3"]="0";
```

The MYSQL trigger code is below, but it doesnt do anything, there are no syntax errors, but it doesnt work, anybody can help?

```
 BEGIN
   IF (NEW.FIELD_ID='3') THEN

     IF (EXISTS(SELECT USER_ID,FIELD_ID,VALUE FROM table WHERE USER_ID=NEW.VALUE)) THEN 

          IF (FIELD_ID='3' AND VALUE!='0') THEN
             SET NEW.VALUE='0'; # <<---NEVER GETS CALLED
          END IF;

     END IF;

  END IF;
 END
```

Comment: Who are user A and B?

Comment: It is not that you do not get no error, you just don't see the error that you get. So try updating the row in an environment that displays errors. `IF (FIELD_ID='3' AND VALUE!='0') THEN` should throw an error when you execute it (when you update the row, not when you create the trigger). MySQL does not know which "field_id" you mean here.

Comment: How do i tell it to check field_id #3? Do i have to loop through all of them by putting a loop inside the IF (EXISTS(SELECT.....)) { loop }?? How do i do that?

Comment: You cannot update the table to which the trigger belongs you can only change the values of the new. elements for the current row (hence the for each row statement).

Comment: You should clarify which values you mean at that point (it is not only unclear to MySQL, but also to me). But I assume you mean the values of the "other" row, so the values you think you retrieved with the select in the if-condition? You can (amongst some other ways) use `IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE USER_ID=NEW.VALUE and FIELD_ID=3 AND VALUE!=0) ...` in that `if` (and remove the 2nd `if`). Also, generally, as mentioned, you should really enable error logging in whatever environment you use. It will not be the last error you will get and don't see and wonder why something doesn't work.